# XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode while installing Crypt-SSLeay-0.65_02

Tags: perl, openssh, openssl, gcc, aix

I am installing a Perl package Crypt-SSLeay-0.65_02 in an AIX 6.1 system but while performing perl Makefile.PL getting the following error.

```
The test suite can attempt to connect to public servers to ensure that the
code is working properly. If you are behind a strict firewall or have no
network connectivity, these tests may fail (through no fault of the code).
Do you want to run the live tests (y/N)? [N] y
================================================================================
Output from 'openssl version -a':
OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010
built on: Tue Jan 21 13:39:08 PST 2014
platform: aix64-gcc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,2,long) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -DOPENSSL_THREADS -pthread -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -maix64 -O -
DB_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
================================================================================
gcc -I/usr/opt/perl5_64/lib/5.10.1/aix-64all/CORE -c -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOU
RCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/
include -maix64 -DUSE_64_BIT_ALL -O -o openssl-version.o openssl-version.c
gcc -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-bdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-b64 -o openssl-version openssl
-version.o


**ld: 0711-738 ERROR: Input file /lib/crt0.o:
        XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode.
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at Makefile.PL line
41, <STDIN> line 1.
Failed to build and link a simple executable using OpenSSL:**
```

It seems crt0.o is 32 bit file but system is 64bit. So i tried compiling the source code for this file to 64 bit but it seems the source code is not available.

Is there any other workaround for this

Comment: Does AIX have multiarch libs? That is, is there a 32-bit subsystem available? Foe example, on Debian and Ubuntu, you can install `ia32-libs` package. See, for example, [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu).

Comment: There is a 64bit file present in the system crt0_64.o in the same location but I don't know why during compilation it is not linking to it.
When I manually linked 32bit crt0.o to 64bit crt0_64.o perl Makefile worked but this is not a solution.
I want to know how I can directly link the Perl package to the 64bit file, which will resolve the issue I suppose.

Comment: Hello! Have you resolved this issue? I have the same problem when compiling pkixshh (a fork of OpenSSH)